# Completely replace an indexing json in Cosmos DB using the .NET API

Tags: .net, api, indexing, azure-cosmosdb

How could I completely replace an indexing json in Cosmos DB using the .NET API?

I am aware of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/how-to-manage-indexing-policy?tabs=dotnetv2%2Cpythonv3#dotnet-sdk) API, but I would like to have a json file locally and just put its contents into an indexing policty using the .NET API. Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two ways you could update Index Policies are using

- SDK
- Azure Portal

Currently there is no way to replace the whole contents as you asked in the question. However you could use A[RM template with Index Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/manage-with-templates#azure-cosmos-account-with-autoscale-throughput) which lets you to define in JSON format to update it.